# How to tackle this weird output of the ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

The second should be a more general form of the first that I need, but it fails to reproduce even the original plot. Whar's with the gray shading obscuring the contours?

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[xl[j, k, 0], {k, .1, 1, .1}], {j, 3/32, 1.2}, 
PlotRange -> {{3/32, 1.2}, {.45, 2.5}}, AxesOrigin -> {3/32, .45}]

ListContourPlot[
Table[{j, xl[j, k, 0], k}, {k, .1, 1, .1}, {j, 3/32, 1.2, .2}], 
PlotRange -> {{3/32, 1.2}, {.45, 2.5}}, AxesOrigin -> {3/32, .45}, 
Contours -> {.1, .2, 3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1.}, 
ContourShading -> None]
```

[image: good output]

[image: output should be same as 1, lines are there, but what's with gray]

Comment: Including definition of `xl` would help.

Comment: Making the title more reflective of the contents would help...

Comment: Love the title!

Comment: How is your title related to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `Flatten` will solve your problem.

```
xl[j_, k_, i_] := Sin[(i + j^2)*k];

data = Flatten[ Table[{j, xl[j, k, 0], k}, {k, .1, 1, .1}, {j, 3/32, 1.2, .2}], 1];

ListContourPlot[data, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thnaks Maple 51 again for solving myoriginal problem as well. The wiggles disappear with more j steps but on the original xl I miss some of the contours I am supplying and get some spurious ones.I am sorry about my title which was inadvertent. If you take me off hold I can post an answer with code and graphs